# EF 6 Code First Migrations not executing Seed method if I configure use of datetime2

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am using Entity Framework database migrations for the first time. It's been a learning experience, but I've got everything working. Almost. For some reason, when I specify that I want columns created as `datetime2` rather than `datetime`, the `Seed` method is no longer called.

In MyDbContext.cs, I specify *MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion*, like so:

```
static MyDbContext()
{
    System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(
            new System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyDbContext, MyDbConfiguration>());
}
```

In MyDbConfiguration.cs, I have a `Seed` method:

```
protected override void Seed(RightToKnowDbContext context)
{
    context.Counties.AddOrUpdate(
        p => p.CountyFips, 
            new County { CountyFips = "001", CountyText = "Adams" },
            new County { CountyFips = "003", CountyText = "Alexander" },
            [...]
            new County { CountyFips = "201", CountyText = "Winnebago" },
            new County { CountyFips = "203", CountyText = "Woodford" }
    );
}
```

When I execute the application the first time, it creates the tables in my database and seeds the Counties table with data, just as desired.

However, I would like it to create columns as `datetime2` rather than as `datetime`. To do this, I add this line to the `OnModelCreating` method in the `MyDbContext` class:

```
modelBuilder.Properties<DateTime>().Configure(c => c.HasColumnType("datetime2"));
```

After making that change, I rollback all migrations in my database to get a fresh start, then run the application for the first time. Just as before, it creates all of the tables, only this time with `datetime2` columns. However, it does not run the `Seed` method (I have confirmed this in the debugger), so the Counties table does not get populated with data. Why?

I have tried numerous variations on this, each time rolling back the database, making a change, then running the application and checking the result. Each time, if I don't have the `datetime2` configuration line, the Counties table is seeded with data, but if I put the line back, it is not.

One thing I've noticed is that, with the `datetime2` configuration in place, after it runs the initial migration, it immediately runs another migration called "202206021857358_AutomaticMigration". My guess is that perhaps it is creating the tables with normal `datetime` columns during the initial migration, then altering the table to use `datetime2` columns instead, and as a result it is for some reason skipping the `Seed` method.

Is there a way to fix this? I realize I could just manually do 'Update-Database' from the Package Manager Console and that would probably avoid the problem, but that's a manual step that I would need to remember to do for each database server (dev, test, QA, and production). I'll do that if I have to, but I would much prefer to use the automated method.

This is Entity Framework 6 (not Core), .Net Framework 4.7.2, and SQL Server 2019.